# nesting depth of a term

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate to find the depth of nesting in a prolog term.
for example : for an atom or variable the depth is zero.
for f(a,b,1,2) the depth is 1.
for f(a,b(7,a),1,2) the depth is 2, etc.
here is what I have so far.

```
% base cases.

 get_depth(Term,0):-
  non_compound(Term),!.
 get_depth(Term,1):-
   Term =.. [_|T],
   all_basic(T),!. % no compound terms in list.
 get_depth(Term,Depth):-
 % this is where I need help.

 % helper prdeicates
  all_basic([T]):-
    non_compound(T),!.
  all_basic([H|T]):-
   non_compound(H),
   all_basic(T).

% term is non compound, either atomic or non instantiated variable.
non_compound(Term):-
 atomic(Term),!;
 var(Term).  

max(X,Y,X):-
 X >= Y,!.
max(_,Y,Y).
```

Comment: Why not use [term_string/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_string/2) and then track open and close parenthesis? e.g. `?- term_string(a(b(C,D),e(F),g),String).
String = "a(b(_10232,_10234),e(_10238),g)"` In other words, don't treat the input as specific types of Prolog terms but instead as a sequence of characters.

Comment: @GuyCoder: the question is, what is the depth of `1+1` for example, I would say 1, since it is a compact form of `+(1, 1)`.

Comment: @GuyCoder: or items with arity zero, like `a()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good questions, I don't know. That is why my comment asked a question. Will have to see if the OP responds.

Comment: anything compound is depth 1 or higher, depends on nesting level, otherwise if atomic or variable then depth is 0.

Comment: I would rather not use any specific prolog built in such as term_string, just plain vanilla prolog.

Comment: @BennyAbramovici So what is the depth of `1+1`? What is the depth of `a()`? Also if one converts a list to dot notation, e.g. `?- write_term([a,b,c], [dotlists(true)]).
.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
true.` So should one convert the input to an AST before processing?

Comment: I am giving this a close vote because the question needs more clarity. The OP is adding more conditions, e.g. `not use any specific prolog built in` as time proceeds.

Comment: no list, just terms in the format:t(a,1,f(12,a),5) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
depth(Term, D) :-
    Term =.. [_|Args],
    (  Args = []
    -> D = 0
    ;  maplist(depth, Args, Ds),
       max_list(Ds, D1), D is D1 + 1
    ).
```

If you do not want maplist and max_list

```
depth(Term, D) :-
    Term =.. [_|Args],
    (  Args = []
    -> D = 0
    ;  max_depth(Args, D1), D is D1 + 1
    ).

max_depth([Term], Max) :- depth(Term, Max).
max_depth([T1, T2| Rest], Max) :-
    depth(T1, D1), max_depth([T2 | Rest], M1),
    (D1 > M1 -> Max = D1; Max = M1).
```

Comment: is this possible without the maplist and max_list since they are implementation specific.

Comment: You can define your own `maplist` and `max_list` easily enough if you want. In fact you actually do not need both, rolling your own `foldl` would do, I think.